# NPM generates error on installation

Tags: node.js, npm

I recently installed `Node.js` on my windows machine, and I am attempting to install express. I go to my start and run the `Command Prompt With Node.js` and I type `npm install express` and I get some poorly descriptive error generated. The contents are as follows:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   'express' ]
2 info using npm@1.4.28
3 info using node@v0.10.33
4 verbose node symlink C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe
5 error Error: ENOENT, stat 'C:\Users\James\AppData\Roaming\npm'
6 error If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
6 error including the npm and node versions, at:
6 error     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
7 error System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
8 error command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "express"
9 error cwd C:\Users\James\Desktop
10 error node -v v0.10.33
11 error npm -v 1.4.28
12 error path C:\Users\James\AppData\Roaming\npm
13 error code ENOENT
14 error errno 34
15 verbose exit [ 34, true ]
```

Also , my command line outputs: `Error: ENOENT, stat 'C:\Users\James\AppData\Roaming\npm'`

What is wrong with my node? What is this mysterious `npm` path in my `AppData`? How can I fix it?

Comment: `ENOENT` means file not found. Ensure that `C:\Users\James\AppData\Roaming\npm` exists, or can be accessed by node (proper permissions).

Comment: That's odd, It would seem something like that would need be generated, but I had to make it myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently I have to create the `npm` directory myself in order for it to work. It would seem as if node would automatically create this.